# How to query a Spring Repository with native SQL

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, repository, prepared-statement

I have a simple React/Spring-Boot app that creates and stores licenses. I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate a search function into the app.

The basic concept is the user enters a string and presses a "search" button which will trigger a query to the API in Spring Boot:

```
license/search/{searchString}
```

The query will search for the same string in a number of different fields. For example

```
select * from licenses where company like "'%" + searchString + "%'" or product like "'%" + searchString + "%'" or etc...
```

How can this be coded using a repository in Spring boot? I already have the controller repository created, but I need to know how to create the query.

Edit: this is the current repository:

```
public interface LicenseRepository extends JpaRepository<License, Long>
{
    License findByFullName(String fullName);
    List<License> findAllByUserId(String id);        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current attempted query may be too complex for a query method.  Instead, consider using the `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM License l WHERE l.company LIKE %:company% OR p.product LIKE %:product%")
List<Movie> searchByCompanyLikeOrProductLike(@Param("company") String company, @Param("product") String product);
```

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks.